# Can a player invite a villager from MY campsite to THEIR island?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I have Bam in my campsite but I don't think I want to invite him into my island. Is there a way for other people to come to my island and invite someone from *my* campsite to *their* island?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. You would need to invite Bam to live on your island and then have him trigger to move out (either by ignoring him or via Amiibo) as other players can only acquire villagers on your island if they're 'in boxes' (moving out).